# Como capturo un mensaje del Backend en el Frontend en stack MERN

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, express

Estamos trabajando en un proyecto de una página con un compañero y cada uno está encargado por separado del proyecto, es decir, él maneja la parte del BackEnd y yo la del FrontEnd usando MERN Stack. La pregunta o más bien inconveniente que tengo es que al hacer un post o envío de datos a la base de datos en el mongo DB esta me retorna un mensaje pero ese mensaje esta presente en el Back, como hago para traerme ese mensaje al Front para que el usuario pueda observar que se almacenaron los datos con éxito, mas en concreto tengo una sección de registro de usuarios y deseo que sí el correo ingresado ya existe pues le avise al usuario que dicho correo ya esta en uso, en el Back esta la función que verifica si el correo existe y me retorna un 'message' pero no se como traerme ese message al Front. Agradezco cualquier orientación,
parte del código:

En el Back:

```
module.exports.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ nombre: req.body.nombre });

  if (user) return res.status(400).json({ message: "el usuario ya existe" });

  const email = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  if (email) return res.status(400).json({ message: "el email ya existe" });

  next();
};
```

En el Front:

```
const enviarDatos = async e => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp',{
        nombre: nombre,
        documento:documento,
        celular: celular,
        contra: contra,
        email:correo
        
    })}
```

De lo anterior si el correo No existe se guardan los datos sin problema, pero si el correo Existe no guarda nada, pero repito, no se como mostrar el mensaje que me retorna el Back.

Comment: Axios devuelve una promesa, entonces, .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })

Comment: Agradezco tu aporte, pero no me devuelve nada: `const enviarDatos = async e => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp',{
        nombre: nombre,
        documento:documento,
        celular: celular,
        contra: contra,
        email:correo
        
    }).then(function (response) { console.log(response.data); })}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el código que propones debería ser:

```
  const enviarDatos = async e => {
    let respuesta = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp',{
        nombre: nombre,
        documento:documento,
        celular: celular,
        contra: contra,
        email:correo
        
    })

   console.log(respuesta)

}
```

Quedaría más limpio sin la función de flecha, aunque para esto tienes que mover de lugar el `async` a la función que contiene este código :

```
const respuesta= await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp',{
        nombre: nombre,
        documento:documento,
        celular: celular,
        contra: contra,
        email:correo

    })

   console.log(respuesta)

}
```

## Edición

Utiliza try -catch

```
try {
    const respuesta= await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp',{
           nombre: nombre,
           documento:documento,
           celular: celular,
           contra: contra,
           email:correo
} catch (e) { console.log(e.request.response) }
    })

   console.log(respuesta)

}// e.request.response; con esto se muestra el mensaje del Back
```

Comment: Hola, agregue el await axios.post a una variable respuesta, pero al momento de correr el código este no llega a la parte donde lo imprimo en consola, es decir la acción se corta o de detiene cuando el correo ya existe, por esta razón es que estoy tratando de capturar el mensaje que se genera en el Back, hice estos combios en el Front para verificar tu aporte:

Comment: `const enviarDatos = async e => {
let respuesta = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp',{
nombre: nombre,
documento:documento,
celular: celular,
contra: contra,
email:correo
})console.log(respuesta)
console.log('valido si función llega hasta aquí')
}` // la función no muestra estos console.log

Comment: Como mencionan en la otra respuesta, captura el error con try-catch. Revisa la edición.

Comment: Excelente, con la edicion que mostraste me funciono, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu petición debe ser controlada por un bloque de `try/catch`, el problema es con ese código estás suponiendo que el servidor siempre te responderá una petición exitosa, pero no controlas los errores, (El código 400 por ejemplo). Te dejo un ejemplo funcional, para ver como funciona el manejo del error, quita de la URL la letra i de api, para que falle y veas la funcionalidad.

```js
const request = async () => {
  
  try {
    const result = await axios('https://randomuser.me/api/');
    return {
      success: true,
      data: result
    }
  } catch( error ) {
    return {
      success: false,
      data: error
    }
  }

};

( async() => {
  
  const result = await request();

  if ( result.success ) {
   console.log('Petición exitosa', result.data);
  } else {
   console.log('Falló la petición', result.data);
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, gracias a @Legna pude traerme el error, y consultando un poco mas traje los atributos de la respuesta y con JSON.parse volví texto la respuesta para poderla mostrar en pantalla mediante uso de SweetAlert, quedando el código en el Front de la siguiente manera:

```
const enviarDatos = async () => {  
        try {await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signUp', {
                nombre: nombre,
                documento: documento,
                celular: celular,
                contra: contra,
                email: correo
            })
            limpiarDatos();
            swal({
                title: "En hora buena!",
                text: "has sido registrado, por favor inicia sesión. Recuerde que el 
                      administrador deberá habilitar y dar su respectivo roll",
                icon: "success",
                buttons: 'cerrar'
            }).then(respuesta => {
                if (respuesta) { window.location.href = '/'}
            })
        } catch (e) {
            let respuesta= JSON.parse(e.request.response).message;
            swal({
                title: "Datos ya existentes!",
                text: ('Por favor revisa los datos ingresados, '+ respuesta),
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: 'cerrar'
            })
        }

    };
```